# I am having difficulty accessing an activeX progress bar's properties in an access2013 form

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an Access Navigation form that is a maximized popup.  I can not use SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter because the form covers the status bar.  I inserted an ActiveX ProgressBar control version 6.0 from the Form Design ribbon.  The problem is I do not know how to access the properties Min, Max, Value that are used to control the bar.  When I code [progressbar control name].Max = 50 I get a runtime error.  How do I access these properties using Access 2013 VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Rooky mistake.  Between posts I restarted my computer.  When I went back to duplicate the error everything worked fine. Looks like it was more a system problem then a code error.  Should have done a restart before posting the first time.  Thanks for your help.